# How can I use multiple connection in If else code blocks?

Tags: vb.net

I want to use multiple connection in if else code block but it's giving the following error when I checked in a Messagebox :

"Argument prompt cannot be converted to string"

Here is my code :

```
    Try
                Conn.Open()
                Com.CommandText = "Select * FROM Table1 WHERE ID=" & txtID.Text & " AND DOR=#01/01/1900# AND Paid = '0' ORDER BY DOI"
                Dr = Com.ExecuteReader
                If Dr.Read = True Then
                    txtInstNo.Text = Dr(2)
                    txtInstAmount.Text = Dr(4)
                Else
                    If MsgBox("Wait! You're not allowed to do it. Do you still want to continue ? ", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Alert") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                        Try
                            Dim Con As New OleDbConnection
                            Dim Comm As New OleDbCommand
                            Dim Dr2 As OleDbDataReader
                            Con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb"
                            Con.Open()
                            Comm.Connection = Con
                            Comm.CommandText = "Select * FROM Table1 WHERE ID=" & txtID.Text & " AND DOR=#01/01/1900# AND Paid = '0' ORDER BY DOI"
                            Comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                            Dr2 = Comm.ExecuteReader
                            MsgBox(Dr2)              <-- Here I got that error
                            If Dr.Read = True Then
                                txtInstNo.Text = Dr(2)
                                txtInstAmount.Text = Dr(4)
                            Else
                                MsgBox("Sorry, no record found",MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
                            End If
                            Dr2.Close()
                            Con.Close()
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MsgBox(ex.Message)
                        End Try
                    End If

                End If
                Dr.Close()
                Conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
```

Comment: What do you want the messagebox to say? `Dr2` is an OleDbDataReader, not a string.

Comment: I was trying to fetch the result which is not available in either text boxes. Can you tell me if the code is correct ? Coz, when I removed the msgbox, it was showing "No data exists for row/column", even I have the results in query which I've created in Access.

Comment: If there are no records found then there is no point repeating the query. Or does the second connection go to a different database? Also, your query is open to SQL injection attacks (if someone typed `0; DROP TABLE Table1;-- ` in txtID then all the records would be deleted) - you should use SQL parameters. There is an example in the Remarks section of [OleDbParameter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @AndrewMorton : No, its from the same database and table but it never shown any data to the textboxes. And thanks for the security check, I'm a beginner here so it'd be great if you can link me to any easy to understand website from where I can get help regarding security.

Answer (score 0):

Your query might be returning entire rows, objects, widgets or whatever.  As @Andrew Morton pointed out, it's a Data Reader.  It's not going to implicitly convert your result.  You'll have to manipulate your reader result and convert it to a string to do anything useful.  You'll also have to handle if your DataReader returns a null result, which when converted should be "" an empty string.

If you just want to see what Dr2 contains, you could try MsgBox(CStr(Dr2)).  No error handling, if it throws an exception.

Comment: MsgBox(CStr(Dr2)) is also incorrect. Without MsgBox, Its showing "No data exists for row/column" even it exists in my database query.

Comment: My bad, forgot it returned an array.  Should be something like this:Dr2.GetString(0).  Gets the value of the specified column as a string.
It's returning a row.  If you want a specific value, might want to execute as a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things which could be modified in your code to make it a bit shorter and so easier to track down what is not working. It is easier to isolate a problem if you have the minimal amount of code which shows the problem: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I'll show my suggestion for a minimal amount of code on a new form which should help you narrow down where the problem is, and then I'll go over why I have written it that way and what could be going wrong.

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer On

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb"
        Dim sql = "SELECT InstNo, InstAmount FROM Table1 WHERE ID = ? AND DOR = #01/01/1900# AND PAID='0' ORDER BY DOI"

        ' lists to hold the retrieved data
        Dim instNos As New List(Of String)
        Dim instAmounts As New List(Of String)

        ' get the data
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@ID",
                                                            .DbType = DbType.String,
                                                            .Value = txtID.Text})
                conn.Open()
                Dim rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                While rdr.Read
                    instNos.Add(rdr.GetString(0))
                    instAmounts.Add(rdr.GetString(1))
                End While

            End Using
        End Using

        ' act on the data
        If instNos.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox(String.Format("No records were found for ID ""{0}"".", txtID.Text))
        Else
            txtInstNo.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, instNos)
            txtInstAmount.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, instAmounts)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

**The code.**

I start with `Option Strict On` to make sure that all data types match up and I haven't done anything else silly which Visual Studio can point out to me.

I use `Option Infer On` so that I don't have to type out the type of variables when the compiler can infer what they are.

I used just one Button on the form along with the three named textboxes as we are going for minimal code.

I set up the two strings which are going to be used in one place at the top of the sub because it is easier to maintain the code that way. Normally, you would declare variables just before they are used to minimise their scope.

I specified exactly which columns I want from the database. There is no point retrieving all of them with `*`. I had to guess what the columns are called - you will need to put in the actual names if they are different.

The result of a query to the database might have more than one record, so I initialise [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s for the data. (Your query has an `ORDER BY` so I assume that there could be more than one record.)

The [Using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) makes sure that resources are released cleanly whatever else happens.

For OleDb, parameters are normally represented by a `?`. (If there is more than one, they are all represented by question marks and the parameters must be added in the order in which they are to be put into the query.) I had to guess at the data type for the ID column - please put in the correct type. When you create the parameter, you can still use a meaningful name for it, even though it is ignored by the computer.

Next, the data (if any) is read. I do nothing else at this point except read the data to keep it fast and tidy. I assumed that the data to be retrieved is strings, hence the [GetString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s. You should adjust that if required, and also the types of the Lists to match.

Now that the data has been read, I act on it. If there was no data, show an appropriate message, and if there was data then I put it into multiline textboxes to show it. Note that I wrote multiline: if it was a single line textbox then only the last line would be visible. Other ways of displaying it could be more useful, for example a DataGridView - in which case I might have read the data into a DataTable or a list of some class.

**What could go wrong.**

In your query, you have `AND DOR = #01/01/1900#` - is this correct?

In your query, you have `AND PAID = '0'` - is `PAID` actually a string? If it is a number then it should be `AND PAID = 0`. (The DB should convert the string "0" to the number zero, but why make it do extra work?)

Now that you have multiline textboxes for the results, you can see if it just happens that the last records found happened to be blank, and are simply not visible in a single-line textbox.

Finally, are you *sure* it is using the correct database file?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you so much for your reply. Codes are correct as I've not converted "Paid" as Number in database yet. I'll follow the coding pattern as you've given. What I want is, If the user has paid today's installment and trying to pay next installment(s) where DOI (DateofInstallment) <>  current date, then the user should get an Alert msg. (i.e "Borrower has already paid his installment for 28-08-15, Do you want to pay the next installment ?",) and if the user click yes, it should recheck the table and show the next installment.

Comment: Hi Andrew, did you get a chance to check my reply ?

Comment: @Abhi That is somewhat different behaviour from the code you showed. To be honest, it is so different that it would merit its own question to show what you have tried and explain what isn't working.

Comment: Its not, if you check my question above its clearly saying that if there are any records for the first query it will fill data and if there is no row, then it'll alert me and if I click yes it should fill the results for the second query. I've two oledbconnection here the first one is in my connection module and the second I created here because the first one was already in use.

Comment: I've tried something and my codes worked, but I've a question that the other Connection string (first one which I've in module) only thats working. The second one is not working, I don't know why even the path is correct(i.e. Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb) It's same as on my Connection module.

Comment: @Abhi I was distracted from the essence of the question. You don't actually need two open connections, as in open1, read, open2, read, close2, close1. You can do open, read, close, open, read, close.